# How to properly use Postgres-style url in Spring Boot application.yml

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to configure Spring datasource using a single string that contains all credentials:

```
postgres://username:secret@localhost/somedb
```

By far I see that `spring.datasource` always requires `username` and `password` properties to be defined separately and `url` property to start with `jdbc:`.
Is there some other way to configure DB connection and use Postgres single string url?

BTW, this url works fine in Python/Django and GoLang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.data.spring.datasource.url) specifies, `spring.datasource.url` is the JDBC URL of the database.

The format of the JDBC url is driver specific, in your case [Postgresql JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html).

You can specify the `username` and `password` of your database inside the JDBC url as connection properties. This is the general format:

> jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?properties

So, in your case: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost/somedb?user=username&password=secret`

Comment: So there is no other way to define Postgres url in application.yml? For example, for Mongo you can use ```spring.data.mongo.uri``` and give one string with credentials.

Comment: The way you define the Postgres url must follow the Driver rules of url formatting. In case of Postgresql JDBC Driver, as far as I know, the only way is the one mentioned in their documentation.